# Pdf with editable Textbox

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pdf-generation

I am created a Pdf report using Webview in Objective-C. Now I want to include an editable textbox in that pdf report. Is there any way to add the textbox programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

No, the PDF creation capabilities within iOS do include controls. You would need a 3rd party product like FoxIT to accomplish this within the PDF.

Comment: could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: First a correction.  The PDF creation capabilities in iOS DO NOT include controls. UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo <https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1623915-uigraphicsbeginpdfpagewithinfo?language=objc> These are graphical drawing methods that can create a PDF with text, images, etc.  There are no methods to create controls that return selections from things like text boxes.  Therefore, to do what you're asking you need to use a 3rd party app that includes more sophisticated functionality.  We use Foxit, of course there are other vendors.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Although this wasn't the answer you were hoping for, I did take sometime to try to help.  You may want to consider an up arrow...